# How to configure Bower API programmatically in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, bower

> file: bower.json
>
> bower.json file contain dependencies, resolutions and overrides object.

```
"name": "XYZ",
"version": "1.0.0",
"dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.5.9",
    "angular-resource": "1.5.9",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.5.9",
    "angular-animate": "1.5.9",
    "angular-ui-router": "0.3.2",
    "ui-router-extras": "0.1.3",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "moment": "2.17.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.2"
}, 
"resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.5.9",
    "angular-animate": "
    "slickgrid": "1.5.0",        
    "lodash": "4.17.2",
    "jquery": "3.1.1",
    "underscore": "^1.8.0"
},
"overrides": {
    "angular": {
         "dependencies": {
              "jquery": "*"
          }
    },
    "lodash": {
          "dependencies": {
               "underscore": "*"
          }
     }
}
```

> NodeJS Code

```
var bowerDependencies = [ 'angular@1.5.9',
  'angular-resource@1.5.9',
  'angular-sanitize@1.5.9',
  'angular-animate@1.5.9',
  'angular-ui-router@0.3.2',
  'ui-router-extras@0.1.3',
  'jquery@3.1.1',
  'moment@2.17.0',
  'lodash@4.17.2'];

bower.commands.install(bowerDependencies, {save: true})
.on('end', function (installed) {
                    console.log(installed);
                });
```

I want to configure resolutions and overrides in bower api (`bower.commands.install`) and also configure  It is possible to execute complete `bower.json` file through `bower.commands.install`.

Answer (score 0):

provide array of resolution and overrides in config part

```
bower.commands.install(bowerDependencies, {save: true}, {/*config resolution and overrides*/})
.on('end', function (installed) {
                    console.log(installed);
                });
```